# Mesh(...) question Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have this code and it plots a Gaussian model correctly, but when attempt to plot it with mesh I have an error, could you please tell how to correct it:

```
covariances = [1 0; 0 1];
Mean = [1 0]
mycolor = 'r';

icov = inv(covariances);
det_cov = det(covariances);
const = 1/(2*pi*sqrt(det_cov));

xx = linspace(Mean(1)-3*sqrt(covariances(1,1)),Mean(1)+3*sqrt(covariances(1,1)));
yy = linspace(Mean(2)-3*sqrt(covariances(2,2)),Mean(2)+3*sqrt(covariances(2,2)));

[x y] = meshgrid(xx,yy);
mx=x-Mean(1);
my = y-Mean(2);

z=const*exp(-0.5*(icov(1,1)*mx.^2+icov(2,1)*mx.*my +icov(2,1)*my.*mx+icov(2,2)*my.^2));

figure(1)
contour(x,y,z,mycolor);
figure(2)
mesh(x,y,z,mycolor);
```

I get a problem with `mesh(x,y,z,mycolor);`

```
??? Error using ==> mesh at 72
Property value pairs expected.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `mycolor` is a string, and not a matrix of color values the same size as `x`, `y`, and `z`, [MESH](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mesh.html) expects it to be entered as a [property/value pair](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/surfaceplotproperties.html), like so:

```
mesh(x,y,z,'EdgeColor',mycolor);
```

I suggest checking out the documentation for more information about [coloring mesh and surface plots](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/visualize/f0-18164.html).

Comment: Is there a way to get different colors depending by z?, like hot red and cold blues in the mesh?

Comment: Or other parameter like 'EdgeColor'?

Comment: @darkcminor: If you leave off any color specification (i.e. `mesh(x,y,z);`) then it will be plotted by default with coloring proportional to the height value in `z`. This coloring will use the default [jet color map](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colormap.html), so you can change to another color map if you don't like it.